# New line in math mode and indent this line

Tags: equations, line-breaking, amsmath, indentation

How can I have a indented new line in math mode?
The line after `\newindentedline` should be indented and start in a new line.

```
\[
    X \subset Y \Rightarrow \forall x \in X: x \in Y \newindentedline
        \Rightwarrow X \subset Y
\]
```

Answer (score 11):

You should read the [mathmode document](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf).

To allow linebreaks inside mathmode you need an environment like `align` (provided by [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    X \subset Y &\Rightarrow \forall x \in X: x \in Y \\
        &\Rightarrow X \subset Y
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

For manual (or more accurate) positioning of the alignment (rather than having it line up with some content in the row above), using the following instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    &X \subset Y \Rightarrow \forall x \in X: x \in Y \\
    & \hspace{4em} \Rightarrow X \subset Y
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

where you specify the indent as the argument to `\hspace{...}`.

To get a unnumbered equation you can use the `align*` (see the comment of egreg)

Comment: @Werner: Feel free to edit the post ;-)

Comment: I'd suggest `split` or `align*`, to be consistent with Sebastian's question.